Marquee resets the first time when text is dynamically loaded from API
I'm working on this marquee in my angular application. I am getting data by calling an API and showing that text in marquee, but when the page reloads and the marquee starts from right to left, as it reaches the end of div, the marquee kind of resets and restarts from right instead of giving an infinite loop. This only happens the first time after page reloads then it works fine. Also it only happens when bringing text through API, if I hard code some text in marquee tag, it works fine
header.component.html div
<div style="width: 50%;font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 500; font-family: serif; color: #4E5E6A;">
    <marquee>{{announcement}}</marquee>
</div>

header.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    const apiurl = environment.applicationRestApiId + "/fetchHeaderAnnouncement";
    this.shared.fetchHeaderAnnouncement(apiurl).subscribe(data => {
      this.announcement = data;
    },error => {
      console.log("Error while fetching Announcement");
    });
   
  }

shared.service.ts
fetchHeaderAnnouncement(url: string) :Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(url,
      {responseType: 'text'}
    );
  }

I'm not using CSS animation because you have to set seconds in it. The speed keeps changing as per the length of text. This doesn't happen on using the marquee tag only.

You should not rely on marquee as it is now deprecated

You can try adding the same text twice, so that it gets rid of this limitation. But note: marquee tag deprecated and should be used with caution since it might stop working in the future.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div style="width: 100%;font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 500; font-family: serif; color: #4E5E6A;">
    <marquee><span>{{announcement}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{announcement}}</span></marquee>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  announcement = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
